# Android: Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix in Manifest for parent tag

Tags: android

in my manifest I use this:

```
<activity
            android:name=".Overlay"
            parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:label="@string/label"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Overlay" >
..
</activity>
```

Everytime I change the xml I get the this error "Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix"
After a project->clean it works until i change the xml again.
android:parent does not exist, so what is the problem here and how to fix it?

thanks
tata

Comment: copy paste your complete manifest file...

Comment: What are you trying to do with `parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`?

Comment: i found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android#comment10440296_2700683 but i think this suggestion is not valid.

Comment: @user1324936 the comment was probably talking about `styles.xml`.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

i have fixed it. it was my fault